# Scale a div using javascript to fill up left over space in sidebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have spent the last hour looking for an example of what i want to do but i cant seem to find it.

Basically i have some content and a side bar. The content is called `"threeposts"` and the sidebar has three divs within it **"interchange", "sidebar2"** and **"pujoin".** Basically i want the "pujoin" div to resize and fill up the different in the height of the content vs the height of the sidebar.

Something like the following,

```
(height of threeposts) - (height of interchange) - (height of sidebar2) = height of pujoin
```

I want to do this with javascript after the page has loaded. Any help would be great thanks. This is the code i have so far.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var main = $("#threeposts").height();
var tone = $("#interchange").height();
var ttwo = $("#sidebar2").height();

$(window).resize(function () {
$('#pujoin') .css({'height': main - tone - ttwo + 'px'});
alert('resized');
});
});
```

Comment: Whats wrong with the javascript you have already out of curiosity?

Comment: If you want someone to help you, clearly you are going to need to provide more information, please read the rules. Advising me "It's not working" is seriously not going to help anyone... Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 Flex layouts can help you achieve this, at the expense of cross-browser operation.
Try this out: http://weblog.bocoup.com/dive-into-flexbox/

Comment: thanks but I have an entire website built I am not going to redesign it when i can just use a little bit of javascript

Comment: They also do not seem to be fully implemented and very much in the initial stages of adoption by only very new browsers.